# Order of lookup in Maven

Tags: git, maven, jenkins, pom.xml

We have the following settings xml

```
<profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>active-repo</id>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>A</id>
                    <url>XXXXX</url>
                    <releases><updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy></releases>
                </repository>
                <repository>
                    <id>B</id>
                    <url>XXXXXX</url>
                    <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
                    <snapshots/>
                </repository>
                <repository>
                    <id>C</id>
                    <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
                    <snapshots><enabled>false</enabled></snapshots> 
                    <url>XXXXX</url>
                </repository>
                <repository>
                    <id>D</id>
                    <url>XXXXX</url>
                    <releases><updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy></releases>
                </repository>
                <repository>
                    <id>E</id>
                    <url>XXXXX</url>
                    <snapshots/>
                </repository>
             </repositories>
```

Surprisingly,dependencies are attempted to be downloaded from repository 'D',overriding the ones mentioned earlier.
Moreover,once the attempt fails with the message below - there is no fallback to the other repositories

```
[INFO] [WARNING] Failure to transfer xxxxxx from XXXXXX was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of D has elapsed or updates are forced.
```

Questions:
How is the order of lookup among the repositories decided?
Why does it not fall back to the other repositories?

There is no explicit repository override for dependency lookup in the pom.

Comment: Just to note: Maven only reports download failure on the last repository it attempted as far as I have seen so far. It will in fact try to download from all of them, but apparently can't find it anywhere.

Comment: We log at info level  - and would have audited attempts on other reporsitories

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the order, but Maven will download snapshot artifacts only from repositories with `snapshots` > `enabled` = `true` and releases (i.e., non-snapshots) only from repositories with `releases` > `enabled` = `true`.

So, it may very well matter what version `xxxxxx` has in your example, as not all repositories are eligible for snapshots and releases, respectively.